# vsc создать свою подсветку синтаксиса для своего языка

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax

Пишу свой язык. И хотел бы написать для него свою подсветку синтаксиса в vsc. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь есть полная документация: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview

Т.е. тебе надо написать своё расширение для VS Code и установить его.